# How can I write the equation in LaTeX and I need the letter t ,r is tiny?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

```
\begin{equation}
\Phi s=\frac{E{\tiny t} r(S,\overline S̄ )+Etrv(S,\overline S̄ )}{|S|(9 )}  
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: You want a subscript so: `E_{tr}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `_` to initiate subscript mode while in math mode. For sure, you need to replace `\Phi s`, `E{\tiny t} r`, and `Etrv` with `\Phi_{s}`, `E_{tr}`, and `E_{trv}`, respectively. Incidentally, `\tiny` is a text-mode command; don't use in math mode.

Depending on what the subscripts `tr` and `trv` mean, they should maybe be rendered in upright ("roman") rather than slanted ("italic") lettering. Both possibilities are pursued in the following code and associated screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} %  optional (for Times Roman text and math font)

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\phi_{S}(W)
&=\frac{E_{tr}(S,\bar{S})+E_{trv}(S,\bar{S})\cdot W}{|S|\cdot(3+6W)} \\[\jot]
&=\frac{E_{\mathrm{tr}}(S,\bar{S})+E_{\mathrm{trv}}(S,\bar{S})\cdot W}{|S|\cdot(3+6W)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: :-) there is a missing (W): to see \upphi_s(W). +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Good catch! Let me fix that right away.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun here a possible solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\upphi_s(W)=\frac{ E_{\textup{tr}}(S,\overline S)+E_{\textup{trv}}(S,\overline S)\cdot W}{|S|\cdot (3+6W)},  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I think, peraphs, that your \upphi is of stix font!